# How should I describe generic types lifetime relationship?

Tags: rust

Assume having a typical example of GAT, referencing iterator:

```
#![feature(generic_associated_types)]
use std::ops::Deref;

trait MyIterator {
    type Item<'a>
    where
        Self: 'a;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Self::Item<'_>;
}
```

For example, I can implement this for `Box<T>`.

```
// This is OK
impl<U> MyIterator for Box<U> {
    type Item<'a> = &'a U
    where
        Self: 'a;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Self::Item<'_> {
        <Box<T> as Deref>::deref(self)
    }
}
```

But not when I generalize it with `Deref` trait:

```
// error[E0309]: the parameter type `U` may not live long enough
impl<T, U> MyIterator for T
where
    T: Deref<Target = U>,
{
    type Item<'a> = &'a U
    where
        Self: 'a;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Self::Item<'_> {
        <T as Deref>::deref(self)
    }
}
```

In my understanding, in the `Box<T>` case compiler somehow knows that the type `U` is owned by `Box<U>` so `U` is assured to live longer than `Box<U>`. So if `Box<U>: 'a` then the compiler can say `U: 'a`.

But this logic is not working for the `Deref<Target=U>` case even though `Deref` has `deref(&self) -> &Self::Target` method, which is implying that for any lifetime `T: 'a` then `U: 'a`.

How can I tell the compiler that the latter case is actually safe?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you are making *both* `T` and `U` into independent type parameters but in fact `U` is always uniquely determined by `T`.

Using the `Deref::Target` type of `T` instead is what you *really* mean, and also makes it easier for the type checker to infer the lifetimes.

```
impl<T> MyIterator for T
where
    T: Deref,
{
    type Item<'a> = &'a <T as Deref>::Target
    where
        Self: 'a;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Self::Item<'_> {
        <T as Deref>::deref(self)
    }
}
```